# Representing Minesweeper Constraints in Sat4J/CNF

Tags: java, sat, sat4j

I'm trying to implement a minesweeper solver using a SAT solver (sat4j) and I have a simple understanding of how they work. But one thing I can't figure out is how to represent the `x+y+Z+....=2` for mines, since SAT solvers use Boolean input. Something such as in the table below:

```
| a | b | c | d | e |
| f | 2 | g | 3 | h |
| i | j | k | l | m |
```

You could write `a+b+c+f+g+i+j+k = 2` and `c+d+e+g+h+k+l+m= 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if by `a+b+c+f+g+i+j+k = 2` you mean that the surrounding cells contain exactly two mines, then your letters really are Boolean variables, and that constraint is called a cardinality constraint.

This is supported out of the box by Sat4j.

You may find some hints here:
https://sat4j.gitbooks.io/case-studies/content/

Comment: Whilst the link provided didn't have what I was looking for, searching the SAT4J API for cardinality constraints gave me exactly the methods I was looking for. Thanks.